# Windows Phone design surface crashes in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (Update 4)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I have created the Windows Phone app using the default Blank App template in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (Update 4). The design surface is crashing with the following error.

I have more than 4GB free memory on PC. I can run the app inside emulator but unable to use the design surface inside visual studio.

Can anyone help me with fixing this?

```
---Error----

An Unhandled Exception has occurred.

Click here to reload the designer

Details:

System.Exception
Package could not be registered.

error 0x80070002: Windows cannot register the package because of an internal error or low memory.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Regards,
Jeevan

Comment: Reboot and maybe re-install Visual Studio. I get this all the time on Windows 10. A reboot always fixes it. You're probably not on Windows 10, but there is probably a similar cause. Does it affect all projects or one specific app?

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1 Enterprise edition. This occurred even after fresh reboot of PC.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting windows store cache might be worth trying as explained at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/windows-81-apps-install-failure-with-error-code/ee1ef24e-5e3d-494c-88c9-c3e66845b53e

Other option if possible would be to create a new user account:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/94a86a71-3eb2-48bb-be91-9540bf1082e9/error-0x80070002-while-loading-mainpage-desinger?forum=wpdevelop